# Cannot use the map function with java SE 8

Tags: java, spring

I am building a spring boot crud app where i have to search for,add and delete custmers.I changed the project compliance to Java 8.

I am following this tutorial  https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-one-to-many-mapping-example/

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{custId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public ResponseEntity<?> deleteCust(@PathVariable int custId) {
        Customer cust=cRep.findOne(custId);
            return cust.map(cust1 -> {
                cRep.delete(cust1);
                return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
            }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("custId " + custId + " not found"));
        }
```

however I am getting the following error:
The method map(( cust1) -> {}) is undefined for the type Customer.can you please help me?Thanks in advance

Comment: The type of `findOne` was changed from `T` to `Optional<T>` in Spring Data 2. Looks like you're using a 1.x version.

Comment: I meant to call map on the result of findOne,in the tutorial it was used without being defined in the class Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `findOne(int)` if you already know the ID either way. `findOne` returns a reference to an object of the target, not an `Optional<T>` anymore. This is the reason why you can't use `map()`

Use `findById` which definitely returns an `Òptional<T>` which you can then map.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{custId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteCust(@PathVariable int custId) {
    return cRep.findById(custId)
               .map(cust1 -> {cRep.delete(cust1); return ResponseEntity.ok().build();})
               .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("custId " + custId + " not found"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cust variable having type of Customer class. Exception is telling you that Customer class havnt the map method. You can try to use `Optional.ofNullable(cRep.findById(custId)).map(...).orElseThrow(...)`